# Eager Loading Relatedto & Target Elements

Tags: templating, eager-loading

I have quite a substantial amount of queries heading out for this bit of code below. I've tried quite a few things to get it down, but I need to eager load some things just to try and reduce the overhead of this, but I still think it won't do enough. Is there anything I can look at to optimise this?

```
    {% set brandIds = craft.entries().section('brands').relatedTo({ targetElement: category }).ids() %}
    {% set offers = craft.entries().section('offers').relatedTo(brandIds).limit(6) %}

    {% for entry in offers %}
      <div class="card category-card">
        <a href="{{ entry.relatedBrand.one.url }}#{{ entry.id }}" title="{{ entry.title }}">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-4">
              {% for asset in entry.relatedBrand.one.brandLogo.all() %}
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset.geturl }}" alt="Card image cap">
              {% endfor %}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 col-8">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{ entry.title }}</h5>
              <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ entry.relatedBrand.one }}</small>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all just a few ideas about best practices

#### Don't

```twig
{{ entry.relatedBrand.one.url }}
{{ entry.relatedBrand.one.title }}
{{ entry.relatedBrand.one.size }}
```

#### Do

```twig
{% set relatedImage = entry.relatedBrand.one() %}
{{ relatedImage.url }}
{{ relatedImage.title }}
{{ relatedImage.size }}
```

Furthermore your code with eager loading

```twig
{% set brandIds = craft
    .entries()
    .section('brands')
    .relatedTo({ targetElement: category })
    .ids() 
%}
{% set offers = craft
    .entries()
    .section('offers')
    .with(['relatedBrand.brandLogo'])
    .relatedTo(brandIds)
    .limit(6) 
    .all()
%}

{% for entry in offers %}
  <div class="card category-card">
    {% set relatedBrand = entry.relatedBrand? entry.relatedBrand[0] : null %}
    <a href="{{ relatedBrand.url?? '' }}#{{ entry.id }}" title="{{ entry.title }}">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-4">
          {% set logos = relatedBrand? relatedBrand.brandLogo : [] %}
          {% for asset in logos %}
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset.geturl }}" alt="Card image cap">
          {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-8">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ entry.title }}</h5>
          <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ relatedBrand.title?? '' }}</small>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Robin! You're amazing! I literally tried 15 things on how to increase the speed of this!!! This has literally nearly halved the load on that query!